# How to validate server certificate against list of CAs during HTTP request using Delphi + Indy

Tags: delphi, ssl, https, indy, x509

As far as I can tell, this is the process to create an HTTPS request using Indy:

1. Create a TIdHTTP object
2. Use a TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL object as its IOHandler
3. Set up this TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL object's SSLOptions and SSLContext to get the proper behaviour before starting the request

However, Indy's documentation is quite minimal as for the possible values for these two SSLOptions and SSLContext objects, even to achieve what seems to me to be pretty standard behaviour.

In particular, I would like to know how to do the following:

- Validate the certificate against either (depending on what is more straightforward) :

  - The local system's trust store
  - A list of root certificates provided with the application
- Drop the connection if the certificate has not been correctly validated.

It seems to me to be the most basic behaviour for an application that needs to call base once in a while: you want to make sure you're really speaking to your own back-end, but still leave you the possibility of changing CAs if you ever need it.

I guess the SSLContext's field rootCertFile should be used, however:

- Nowhere is it said in what format the rootCertFile should be provided (pem? der? pkcs something?)
- It is in no way obvious how one should process to configure several alternatives root certificates.

Can someone provide the method, and if possible, some sample code on how this behaviour can be achieved?